# How to insert a continue statement inside an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

My code is below. I am using C language. I want to repeat the action from the start if the user types `Y` but I am confused how can I make that happen.

I tried to look for a solution but the results doesn't fit for my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int A, B;

    char Y, N, C;

    printf ("Enter value 1: ");
    scanf ("%i", &B);
    printf ("\nEnter value 2: ");
    scanf ("%i", &A);
    printf ("= %i", A + B);

    printf ("\n\nAdd again? Y or N\n");
    scanf ("%c", &C);
    if (C == Y) {
//This should contain the code that will repeat the:
        printf ("Enter value 1: ");
        scanf ("%i", &B);
        printf ("\nEnter value 2:
    } else if (C == N)
        printf ("PROGRAM USE ENDED.");
    else
        printf ("Error.");
}
```

Comment: You  can only use continue\break in iteration statement.

Comment: You could take inside a function that part, if you enter "Y", you could invoke that function.

Comment: Add code in increments, and test it. It takes time but you'll learn a lot. [C Programming/Program flow control] (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Program_flow_control) check the loop structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just wrap your code inside a `for` loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int A, B;
    char Y = 'Y', N = 'N', C;

    for (;;) {     // same as while(1)
        printf("Enter value 1: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &B) != 1)
            break;
        printf("\nEnter value 2: ");
        if (scanf("%i", &A) != 1)
            break;

        printf("%i + %i = %i\n", A, B, A + B);

        printf("\n\nAdd again? Y or N\n");
        // note the initial space to skip the pending newline and other whitespace
        if (scanf(" %c", &C) != 1 || C != Y)
            break;
    }
    printf("PROGRAM USE ENDED.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors in your program.
Syntax error: please resolve it on your own.
There is no need for Y and N to be declared as character, you can use them directly as they are not storing any value.
NOW, there is no need for continue you can use while loop.
I have resolved your problem. Please take a look

Also, you are using a lot of scanf so there is an input buffer, a simple solution to it is using getchar() which consumes the enter key spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A, B;
    char C = 'Y';

    while (C == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Enter value 1: ");
        scanf("%i", &B);
        printf("\nEnter value 2");
        scanf("%i", &A);
        printf("= %i\n", A + B);
        getchar();
        printf("\n\nAdd again? Y or N\n");
        scanf("%c", &C);
    }
    if (C == 'N')
    {
        printf("PROGRAM USE ENDED.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work on if-elseif-else codes?

Comment: Yes it will work in if-else if-else codes.